# How to get list of internal entities?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I have two classes - Employee and Job - as a domain

```
public class Employee {
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<>();
   private Week week;

   public Employee() {
   }

   public Employee(String name) {
       this.name = name;
       jobList.add(new Job("Haircut", 30, 300));
       week = Week.init();
   }
//Getters and setters for all fields.
}

public class Job {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private int duration;
    private int price;

    public Job() {
    }

    public Job(String title, int duration, int price) {
        this.duration = duration;
        this.price = price;
        this.title = title;
    }
//Getters and setters for all fields.
}
```

and as a backend

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Week week;

    public Employee() {
    }
    //Getters and setters for all fields.
}

@Entity
public class Job {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private int duration;
    private int price;

    public Job() {
    }
    //Getters and setters for all fields.
}
```

registered in OfyService

```
public class OfyService {

    static {
        factory().register(Employee.class);
        factory().register(Job.class);
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

There are two methods in my EmployeeEndpoint:

```
@ApiMethod(
    name = "list",
    path = "employee",
    httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<Employee> list(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursor, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
    limit = limit == null ? DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT : limit;
    Query<Employee> query = OfyService.ofy().load().type(Employee.class).limit(limit);
    if (cursor != null) {
        query = query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursor));
    }
    QueryResultIterator<Employee> queryIterator = query.iterator();
    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>(limit);
    while (queryIterator.hasNext()) {
        employeeList.add(queryIterator.next());
    }
    return CollectionResponse.<Employee>builder().setItems(employeeList).setNextPageToken(queryIterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString()).build();
}

@ApiMethod(
    name = "jobList",
    path = "employee/{id}/jobList",
    httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<Job> jobList(@Named("id") Long employeeId) {
    int limit = DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT;
    Query<Job> query = OfyService.ofy().load().type(Job.class).limit(limit);
    QueryResultIterator<Job> queryIterator = query.iterator();
    List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<>(limit);
    while (queryIterator.hasNext()) {
        jobList.add(queryIterator.next());
    }
    return CollectionResponse.<Job>builder().setItems(jobList).setNextPageToken(queryIterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString()).build();
}
```

I can see employee on server with *list()* method and there is one Job listed inside of employee:

```
200

{
    "items": [
   {
   "id": "5732568548769792",
   "name": "Sophie",
   "jobList": [
      {
       "title": "Haircut",
       "duration": 30,
       "price": 300
      }
   ],
...
}
```

But when I try to get this Job by means of *jobList()* method with id = 5732568548769792 it returns nothing:

```
200

{
 "kind": "employeeApi#resourcesItem",
 "etag": "\"eEm63BNCBzxEAy3aqxetQdspGKA/FzFIL_vxOIIBu5chWZYooI-ArvQ\""
}
```

If I specify ancestor with

```
Query<Job> query = OfyService.ofy().load().type(Job.class).ancestor(Key.create(Employee.class, employeeId)).limit(limit);
```

in *jobList()* the result does not change.

**What should I change in the code above to get desired job list?**

Answer (score 0):

According to your entity model there is no relationship between Employee and Job entity.So can not perform ancestor query on Job entity because it doesn't have any ancestor(parent).

Moreover Employee entity has joblist attribute . it means You can get list of job of employee after getting that employee using **employee.getjobList()** getter method of jobList in Employee Entity.

Better way is to change your entity model and create a relationship between Employee and Job then get entities using Web safe key e.g.

Change:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Week week;

    public Employee() {
    }

    //Getters and setters for all fields.
}

@Entity
public class Job {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private int duration;
    private int price;

    public Job() {
    }
    //Getters and setters for all fields.
}
```

To:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    private Week week;

    public Employee() {
    }
public String getWebsafeKey() {
        return Key.create(Employee.class, id).getString();
    }
    //Getters and setters for all fields.
}

@Entity
public class Job {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private int duration;
    private int price;
@Index
    @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
    Ref<Employee> employeeRef;
    public Job() {
    }
 public String getWebsafeKey() {
        return Key.create(employeeRef.getKey(), Job.class, id).getString();
    }
    //Getters and setters for all fields.
}
```

this model return you the websafe key of the entity you create in response. use this websafe whenever you want to access the created entity.
when you create a job , create a relationship of the job to be created with the Employee which is already created using:

```
 job.employeeRef = Ref.create(employeeKey);
```

After that change your Api method:

```
@ApiMethod(
    name = "jobList",
    path = "employee/{id}/jobList",
    httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<Job> jobList(@Named("id") Long employeeId) {
    int limit = DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT;
    Query<Job> query = OfyService.ofy().load().type(Job.class).limit(limit);
    QueryResultIterator<Job> queryIterator = query.iterator();
    List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<>(limit);
    while (queryIterator.hasNext()) {
        jobList.add(queryIterator.next());
    }
    return CollectionResponse.<Job>builder().setItems(jobList).setNextPageToken(queryIterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString()).build();
}
```

To:

```
@ApiMethod(
    name = "jobList",
    path = "employee/{employee_web_safe_key}/jobList",
    httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<Job> jobList(@Named("employee_web_safe_key") String employeeWSKey) {
    int limit = DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT;
    Query<Job> query = OfyService.ofy().load().type(Job.class).limit(limit);
query=query.filter("employeeRef =",Key.create(employeeWSKey))
    QueryResultIterator<Job> queryIterator = query.iterator();
    List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<>(limit);
    while (queryIterator.hasNext()) {
        jobList.add(queryIterator.next());
    }
    return CollectionResponse.<Job>builder().setItems(jobList).setNextPageToken(queryIterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString()).build();
}
```

This will give you all the jobs related to given employee.

You can also perform ancestor query if you create your model by adding @Parent index on  Ref employeeRef;
e.g.

```
@Parent
@Index
@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
Ref<Employee> employeeRef;
```

Comment: Thanks, Baqir. Unfortunately, I have no time right now to check your answer, but I will do it for sure.

Comment: its ok @isabent, i can understand. During your checking if you will find the answer is helpful , just raise me. :)